# Need suggestion for handling large number of timers/timeouts

Tags: c, multithreading, timer

I am working on redesign an existing L2TP(Layer 2 tunneling protocol) code.
For L2TP , the number of tunnels we support is 96K. L2TP protocol has a keep-alive mechanism where it needs to send HELLO msges.

Say if we have 96,000 tunnels for which L2TPd needs to send HELLO msg after configured timeout value , what is the best way to implement it ?

Right now , we have a timer thread , where for every 1sec , we iterate and send HELLO msges. This design is a old design which is not scaling now.

Please suggest me a design to handle large number of timers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to implement timers:

1) select: this system call allows you to wait on a file descriptor, and then wake up.  You can wait on a file descriptor that does nothing as a timeout

2) Posix Condition Variables: similar to select, they have a time out mechanism built in.

3) If you are using UNIX, you can set a UNIX signal to wake up.

Those are basic ideas.  You can see how well they scale to multiple timers; I would guess you'd have to have multiple condvars/selects for some handful of the threads.

Dependingo on the behaviour you want, you would probably want a thread for every 100 timers or so, and use one of the mechanisms above to wake up
one of the timers.  You'd have a thread sitting in a loop, and keeping
track on each of the 100 timeouts, then waking up.

Once you exceed 100 timers, you would simply create a new thread and have it manage the next 100 timers and so on.

I don't know if 100 is the right granularity, but it's something you'd play with.

Hopefully that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that, by default the 'select' cannot monitor more than 1024 file descriptors at same time .

Comment: Actually, it can.  You have to "unlimit" you descriptors (to make sure you can actually use more than 1024 descriptors) and then you have to recompile your code after setting FD_SETSIZE to a larger value before you include the appropriate includes.  This is a little niggly but it works because select is usually implemented as a bitvector, where a 1 in the bit means that file descriptor is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such requirements are met with a delta-queue.  When a timeout is required, get the system tick count and add the timeout interval to it.  This gives the Timeout Expiry Tick Count, (TETC).  Insert the socket object into a queue that is sorted by decreasing TETC and have the thread wait for the TETC of the item at the head of the queue.

Typically, with asocket timeouts, queue insertion is cheap because there are many timeouts with the same interval and so new timeout insertion will normally take place at the queue tail.

Management of the queue, (actually, since insertion into the sorted queue could take place anywhere, it's more like a list than a queue, but whatever:), is best kept to one timeout thread that is normally performing a timed wait on a condvar or semaphore for the lowest TETC.  New timeout-objects can then be queued to the thread on a thread-safe concurrent queue and signaled to the timeout-handler thread by the sema/condvar.

When the timeout thread becomes ready on TETC timeout, it could call some 'OnTimeout' method of the object itself, or it might put the timed-out object onto a threadpool input queue.

Such a delta-queue is much more efficient for handling large numbers of timeouts than any polling scheme, especially for requirements with longish intervals.  No polling is required, no CPU/memory bandwidth wasted on continual iterations and the typical latency is going to be a system clock-tick or two.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on the processor/OS, kernel version, architecture.

In linux, one of the option is to use its timer functionality for multiple timers. Addition of timer can be done using add_timer in linux. You can define it using timer_list and initilialize internal values of timer using init_timer.
Followed by it register it using add_timer after filling timer_list(timeout(expire), function to execute after timeout(function), parameter to the function(data)) appropriately for respective timer. If jiffies is more than or equal to timeout(expire), then the respective timer handler(function) shall be triggered.

Some processors have provisioning for timer wheels(that consists of a number of queues that are placed equally in time in slots) which can be configured for a wide range of timers,timeouts as per the requirement.